# 500 (Internal Server Error) when uploading an Image to AWS S3 via Elastic Beanstalk Application

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-php-sdk

My task is to make an application using AWS Elastic Beanstalk and S3 where an Image can be uploaded/deleted from the user.

I am using the BlueImp library : "https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload"

as well as the modified version of UploadHandler.php :"https://gist.github.com/tim-peterson/8172999"

I have installed aws-php-sdk using Composer inside the application and created a config.php file as follows:

```
<?php return[
's3' => [
    'key' => '***',
    'secret' => '***',
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
    'bucket' => 'my-bucket'
]];?>
```

But when I try to upload an Image it shows an error : "500 (Internal Server Error)"

Any ideas why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should check the logs because 500 (Internal Server Error) is too broad to pinpoint the exact issue. Please note that when you run an app on Elastic Beanstalk, you will have ec2 instance(s) created and running where you can ssh and see what's going on in the server.